# Jest [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, computed-properties

I am relatively new to Jest unit testing. I have a Child component DataList.vue with a Buefy tag that has a v-bind as follows:

```
<b-tag :type="currentStatus.type" class="statustag">
    {{ currentStatus.statusText }}
    <b-icon
      :icon="currentStatus.icon"
      size="is-small"
      class="tagicon"
    ></b-icon>
  </b-tag>
```

And in the script tag, I have the following computed property:

```
get currentStatus() {
    return this.statusOptions
      .filter(status => status.status == this.item.status)
      .shift();
  }
  private statusOptions = [
    {
      status: 'Success',
      statusText: 'Success',
      type: 'is-primary',
      icon: 'check-circle'
    },
    {
      status: 'Fail',
      statusText: 'Fail',
      type: 'is-primary',
      icon: 'close-circle'
    },
  ];
```

When I shallow mount the component and write any unit test and run it, I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"
```

Similary with `statusText` and `icon`.

The component is rendered fine on the browser and the unit tests for the remaining part of the component works when I comment the b-tag element out.
Any help on how to get jest test the b-tag element correctly is appreciated.